# Retrieving request parameters from FormData api for servlets prior to 3.0 where request.part is not supported

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, xmlhttprequest, form-data

Basically i am trying to send form parameters as a post data to another jsp and print the paramters but i encounter problems accomplishing this. Below is the html code which constructs a FormData instance and send it as post data of XMLHttpRequest to a target jsp.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function loadXMLDoc()
    {
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('firstname', 'peter');
    form.append('lastname', 'parker');
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","sample.jsp",true);
    xmlhttp.send(form);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="myDiv"><h2>Text which will be changed on click</h2></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The target jsp servlet code goes like this where i try to retrieve the parameters appended to FormData instance.

```
<%
    out.println(request.getParameter("firstname"));
    out.println(request.getParameter("lastname"));
%>
```

But when i try to run the jsp, i get the parameters printed to be null. I am new to ajax and the world of client side scripting. So can someone please explain how do i successfully retrieve the parameters from FormData instance?

Comment: y arent u using jquery ajax?

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone: i don't know jquery as am getting started with working client side. That's why

Comment: Ok i will help u wid that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "#button_click" ).click(function(){
var form= new FormData();
    form.append('firstname', 'peter');
    form.append('lastname', 'parker');
$.ajax({
    url: 'sample.jsp',
    data: form,
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
});
});

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Text which will be changed on click</h2></div>
 <button id="button_click" type="button">Change Content</button>
```

Also you will require these header above

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Now request and let me know if it works

**Update**

try this jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Ujryx/25/

HTML

```
<form id="formoid" action="sample.jsp" title="" method="post">
    <div><label class="title">First Name</label><input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" ></div>
<div><label class="title">Name</label><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" ></div>
<div><input type="submit" id="submitButton"  name="submitButton" value="Submit"></div>
```

JS

```
$("#formoid").submit(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $( this ),
      url = $form.attr( 'action' );

  var posting = $.post( url, { firstname: $('#firstname').val(), lastname: $('#lastname').val() } );


  posting.done(function( data ) {
    alert('success');
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks but unfortunately it doesn't work.. nothing happens on button click

Comment: did u put the script?ok try this.open in chrome press ctrl+shift+i,this is d developer console...n c if u r getting errors..

Comment: ya i added the script

Comment: ok try this.open in chrome press ctrl+shift+i,this is d developer console...n c if u r getting errors.

Comment: @aarish try now..there was an extra bracket

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55310/discussion-between-aarish-and-santino-sonny-corleone).